# How to debug only specific product element?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, debugging

I have over 1000 products on my website. To load each of them, I call one specific function which performs some actions.
One of these products loads wrong and I want to debug it. How can activate debugger specifically for this product?

Because for now, when I put inject a debugger directly to this function it triggers for each product. This is not convenient

Thank you

Comment: Can you add an example of what you inject for debugging? If you know for example the id of this product, you could test the id to debug only this one

Comment: I had a database of 20,000 items.
One item with quotes/double-quotes/other crashed the whole thing.
Something to check...